# Tableau question: How to link a reference table to a dynamic calculated field value (which is an integer)? I'm assigning P values

Tags: join, aggregate, tableau-api, calculated-field

Since Tableau does not have a function for P-values(correct me if I'm wrong here) I created a spreadsheet with all possible sample sizes under two different alphas/significance levels and need to connect the appropriate p-value to a calculated field from the main database source (aggregate count of people).  I assumed I could easily match numbers with a condition to bring back the p-value in a calculated field yet I'm hitting a brick wall.  Biggest issue seems to be that the field I want to join the P-value reference table to is an aggregated integer. Also, I do not have any extensions and my end result needs to be an integer, not a graph.

Any secret tricks here?

Seems I cannot blend the reference table in nor join it to an aggregate?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around in calculating the critical value for a two tailed t-test in tableau.  However, I didn't figure out how to join based on an aggregated calculated field. Work around: I used a conditional statement just copying and pasting about 100 critical values based on (sample size - 2) aka degrees of freedom,  into a calculated field.  To save time, use excel to pull down the conditions to 120.  Worked like a charm!

Here is the conditional logic for alpha = .2 (80%) in two tailed t-test (replace the ## line with about 117 rows):

```
IF  [degrees of freedom] =  1   THEN    3.08
ELSEIF  [degrees of freedom] =  2   THEN 1.89
ELSEIF  [degrees of freedom] =  3   THEN 1.64
##ELSEIF [...calculate down to 120] = ... then ...   
ELSEIF  [degrees of freedom]  > 121  THEN 1.28
END
```